# Erdos theorem about tournaments with specific property

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, extremal-combinatorics

> A *tournament* is an oriented graph $T=(V,E)$ such that $(x,x)\notin
>  E$ for all $x\in V$, and for any two vertices $x\neq y$ exactly one of
> $(x,y)$ and $(y,x)$ belongs to $E$. That is, each tournament is
> obtained from a complete graph by orienting its edges. The name
> tournament is natural, since one can think of the set $V$ as a set of
> players in which each pair participates in a single match, where
> $(x,y)\in E$ iff $x$ beats $y$.
>
> Say that a tournament has the property $P_k$ if for every set of $k$
> players there is one who beats them all, i.e. , if for any subset
> $S\subseteq V$ of $k$ playes there exists a player $y\notin S$ such
> that $(y,x)\in E$ for all $x\in S$.
>
> **Threorem 3.1 (Erdos 1963)** *If $n\geq k^22^{k+1}$, then there is a tournament of $n$ players that has the property $P_k$.*
>
> *Proof.* Consider a random tournament of $n$ players, i.e., the outcome of every game is determined by the flip of fair coin. For a set
> $S$ of $k$ players, let $A_S$ be the event that no $y\notin S$ baets
> all of $S$. Each $y\notin S$ has probability $2^{-k}$ of beating all
> of $S$ and there are $n-k$ such possible $y$, all of whose chances are
> mutually independent. Hence $\text{Pr}[A_S]=(1-2^{-k})^{n-k}$ and
> $$\text{Pr}\left[\cup A_S\right]\leq
>  \binom{n}{k}(1-2^{-k})^{n-k}<\frac{n^k}{k!}e^{-(n-k)/2^k}\leq
>  n^ke^{-n/2^k}.$$ If $n\geq k^22^{k+1}$, this probability is strictly
> smaller than $1$. Thus, for such an $n$, with positive probability no
> events $A_S$ occurs. This means that there is a point in the
> probability space for which none of the events $A_S$ happens. This
> point is a tournament $T$ and this tournament has the property $P_k$.

This is an excerpt from Jukna's book "Extremal combinatorics". I am learning Chapter 3 which is Probabilistic Counting. I am not so familiar with probability theory except basic definitions but the author provides some information in the previous paragraph such as finite probability space, random variable, its mean and the notion of randomness.

I'd be very thankful if someone can explain me some unclear moments from this excerpt.

1. I suppose that the probability space here is $(\Omega,P)$, where $\Omega$ is family of all possible tournaments between $n$ players and obviously $|\Omega|=2^{\binom{n}{2}}$ and for each $\omega\in \Omega$ we suppose $\text{Pr}[\omega]=2^{-\binom{n}{2}}$. Is that correct?

2. I did not understand why $\text{Pr}[A_S]=(1-2^{-k})^{n-k}$. Can anyone explain that in detail, please?
3. I understood the first inequality which follows from the fact that $\text{Pr}(\cup_{i=1}^{N}A_i)\leq\sum \limits_{i=1}^N \text{Pr}(A_i)$ but I did not understand the last two, though, I know that $\binom{n}{k}\leq \frac{n^k}{k!}$. Can anyone explain that also please?

I'll highly appreciate your help! Thanks!

**EDIT:** For some reason in my computation I obtained that $\text{Pr}[A_S]=2^{-k(n-k)}$. Because $A_S=\{\omega \in \Omega: \text{no}\ y\notin S \ \text{beats all of}\ S\}$. So we need to fix $n-k$ edges from each vertex belonging to $S$ which is in total $k(n-k)$. Hence we have remaining ${\binom{n}{2}}-k(n-k)$ edges and on each of them we can define 2 directions. It shows that that the answer is $\dfrac{2^{\binom{n}{2}-k(n-k)}}{2^{\binom{n}{2}}}=2^{-k(n-k)}.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your pobability space is correct.
2. > So we need to fix $n−k$ edges from each vertex belonging to S which is in total $k(n−k)$.

We would need to fix this number of edges if the wanted every $y\notin S$ to beat all of $S$. (Because we would fix every edge between $V\setminus S$ and $S$ to the direction $V\setminus S$ to $S$. But if we want every $y\notin S$ to **not** beat all of $S$, we need for each $y\notin S$ at least one edge not directed to $S$, which is more permissive. The probability that $y$ does not beat all $S$ is the complementary of $y$ beat all of $S$, so it has probability $1-2^{-k}$. These probabilities are all independant for the $n-k$ vertices outside of $S$, so we get $(1-2^{-k})^{n-k}$.

3. Second inequality : $1+x\leq e^x$ so $(1+x)^r\leq e^{rx}, r>0$
   Third inequality : This is straightforward to see that $e^{k/2^k}\leq e^{1/2} \leq k!, k\geq 2$. This is wrong if $k = 1$,  but the theorem is trivial in this setting.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I am reading it carefully. But was I right with the finite probability space $(\Omega, \text{Pr})$?

Comment: So I defined the finite probability space $(\Omega,\text{Pr})$ as follows: $\Omega$ - the family of all tournaments on $n$ players. Hence $|\Omega|=2^{\binom{n}{2}}$ and $\text{Pr}[\omega]=2^{-\binom{n}{2}}$ for each $\omega\in \Omega$. Suppose that $V=\{p_1,\dots,p_n\}$ be the set of players. WLOG assume that $S=\{p_1,\dots,p_k\}$. Define $A_S:=\{\omega\in \Omega: \text{no}\ y\notin S \ \text{beats all of}\ S\}$.

Comment: One can see that $A_S=\bigcap\limits_{j=1}^{n-k}A_S^{(j)}$ where $A_S^{(j)}:=\{\omega\in \Omega: \ p_{j+k}\notin S \ \text{does not beat all of}\ S\}$ for $1\leq j\leq n-k$.

I know that $\text{Pr}[A_S^{(j)}]=1-2^{-k}$. But how it follows that $\text{Pr}[A_S]=(1-2^{-k})^{n-k}$?

I am not so familiar with probability theory except basic definitions. Can you explaim that moment please?

Comment: @PlayGame Your probability space is right. If $A$ and $B$ are two independent events, then $\Pr(A\bigcap B) = Pr(A)Pr(B)$. Two events are independent if the issue of one event have no correlation on the other. Here, the sets of edges from $y\notin S$ to $S$ are disjoint for all $y$, so the corresponding probabilities will be independent.

Comment: I was wondering can you give a more detailed explananation for that, please? I really have issues to understand that. I have never seen this before and I'd be grateful if I can see this for the first time in details

Comment: @PlayGame Suppose you have two urns, the first with $n_1$ balls, $k_1$ white and $n_1-k_1$ black, and second one with $n_2$ balls, $k_2$ white and $n_2-k_2$ black. We take one ball in each urn. Let $W_i$ be the event "we get a white ball in urn i", $Pr(W_1) = \frac{k_1}{n_1}$, $Pr(W_2) = \frac{k_2}{n_2}$. The ball we get in urn 1 does not influence the result in urn 2, so $W_1$ and $W_2$ are independent. From the $n1n_2$ possible ways to draw balls, we have $k_1k_2$ possibilities to get to white balls, so $Pr(W_1\bigcap W_2) = \frac{k_1k_2}{n_1n_2} = Pr(W_1)Pr(W_2)$.

Comment: I still cannot get why $P(W_1\cap W_2)=\frac{k_1k_2}{n_1n_2}$. I am still very confused. I guess the question why those events are independent should be proved in a rigorous way with details, I think. Can we do that?

Comment: How you can take the intersection of $W_1$ and $W_2$ if they have different structure? Can you give a detailed answer to my question, please?

Comment: I agree with @PlayGame. What you have shown is not rigorous at all especially for beginner. He have shown enough and I think the better answer could be given to his question about independence of events.

Comment: @PlayGame If you want more in depth definitions, you should probably take a book of probabilities, it's hard to explain these kind of things in a 500 characters comments. $W_1\bigcap W_2$ means both $W_1$ and $W_2$ are realized, so we got a white ball in urn 1 and a white ball in urn 2. The total number of outcomes is $n_1n_2$ ($n_1$ possible outcomes in the first urn, $n_2$ in the second). The total number of outcome for $W_1\bigcap W_2$ is $k_1k_2$ ($k_1$  possibilities of  getting a white ball in urn 1, $k_2$ in urn 2), so the probability is $\frac{k_1k_2}{n_1n_2}$.

Comment: This is not a definition, more an example which should give intuition about independence of events. The definition of $A$ and $B$ are independent is $P(A\bigcap B) = P(A)P(B)$, so the "rigorous way" of proving independence is by computing the probability as I did, by enumerating the possible outcomes.

Comment: To be honest yesterday all day long I was reading book on probability theory and learnt some new stuff but let's be more precise: I defined the finite probability space $(\Omega, P)$ with uniform probability distribution. We considered the event $A_S$ which can be written as the intersection of finitely many events, i.e. $A_S=A_S^1\cap\dots \cap A_S^m$.
In almost every book which I read the definition of independence is as follows: The events $A,B$ are independent, if $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$.

Comment: So look we have the following situation: We have events $A_S,,A_S^1,\dots,A_S^m$ such that $A_S=A_S^1\cap \dots\cap A_S^m$. You cannot claim in words that they are independent and then write $P(A_S)=P(A_S^1)\dots P(A_S^m)$. 

You need to calculate $P(A_S)$ and show that it is equal to $P(A_S^1)\dots P(A_S^m)$ and only after that you can claim that they are independent. I  hope I was clear.

Comment: @PlayGame Ok, lets take this rigorously. Lets fix an canonical orientation for each edge,  let $A_e$ the event: $e$ is oriented in its canonical orientation. Your defined your probability space uniformly over all possible orientation of all edges. It's easy to see that half of the orientations have $e$ oriented in canonical orientation, and half have $e$ oriented in reverse orientation, so $P(A_e)=1/2$. Similarly, we can show that for two distinct edges $e_1$ and $e_2$, $P(A_{e_1}\bigcap A_{e_2})=1/4$ by enumerating the possibilities, so $A_{e_1}$ and $A_{e_2}$ are independent.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135408/discussion-between-caduk-and-playgame).

Comment: Hello! I was wondering if you have some spare time can you take a look at my recent post please? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4424100/existence-of-universal-n-k-sets

Comment: Hello! Can you join a chat please?