# Existence of universal $(n,k)$ sets

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, extremal-combinatorics

> A set of $0-1$ strings of length $n$ is $(n,k)$-*universal* if, for
> any subset of $k$ coordinates $S=\{i_1,\dots,i_k\}$, the projection
> $$A\upharpoonright_S:=\{(a_{i_1},\dots,a_{i_k}):(a_1,\dots,a_n)\in
>  A\}$$ of $A$ onto the coordinates in $S$ contains all possible $2^k$
> configurations.
>
> **Theorem 3.2 (Kleitman-Spencer 1973).** *If $\binom{n}{k}2^{k}(1-2^{-k})^r<1$ , then there is an $(n,k)$-universal
> set of size $r$.*
>
> *Proof.* Let $A$ be a set of $r$ random $0-1$ strings of length $n$, each entry of which takes values $0$ or $1$ independently and with
> equal probability $1/2$. For every fixed set $S$ of $k$ coordinates
> and for every fixed vector $v\in \{0,1\}^k$,
>
> $$\text{Pr}[v\notin A\upharpoonright_S]=\prod \limits_{a\in
>  A}\text{Pr}[v\neq a\upharpoonright_S]=\prod \limits_{a\in
>  A}(1-2^{-|S|})=(1-2^{-k})^r.$$ Since there are only $\binom{n}{k}2^k$
> possibilities to choose a pair $(S,v)$, the set $A$ is not
> $(n,k)$-universal with probability at most
> $\binom{n}{k}2^k(1-2^{-k})^r$, which is strictly smaller than $1$.
> Thus, at least one set $A$ of $r$ vectors must be $(n,k)$-universal,
> as claimed.

This is an excerpt from Jukna's book "Extremal combinatorics" which I am reading to understand the essence of probabilistic method in combinatorial problems. I am not so familiar with probability theory but I know some basics so I'd like to clarify some moments from the proof of this theorem.

Questions.

1. Usually authors do not write explicitly what the probability space is in certain examples but I am a beginner so I'd like to understand the details. We have $\{0,1\}^n$ - binary string of length $n$ and there $2^n$ such strings. From the context I see that the probability space is the following: $(\Omega,\text{Pr}),$ where $\Omega:=\{A\subset \{0,1\}^n: |A|=r\}$, i.e. $|\Omega|=\binom{2^n}{r}$ and probability distribution is uniform, i.e. $\text{Pr}[A]=\frac{1}{|\Omega|}$. Is my guess correct?
2. What is $[v\notin A\upharpoonright_S]$? I guess it is some event, i.e. subset of $\Omega$, but I cannot write it explicitly. Can explain what is this please? Initially I thought that $[v\notin A\upharpoonright_S]$ is the same as $\{A\in \Omega: v\notin A\upharpoonright_S\}$ but it does make sense  since in the next equality he is taking product over all element of $A$.

I have two questions so far because I need to understand those moments in order to move forward.
I'd be very thankful for help!

**EDIT:** 3) I am slightly confused with the definition of $(n,k)$ universal set. Let's take $n=3, k=2$ and consider the following set of binary strings of length $3$, say $\mathcal{A}=\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(1,1,0),(0,0,1)\}$. Then we have the following set of coordinates $S_{12}=\{1,2\},\ S_{13}=\{1,3\},\ S_{23}=\{2,3\}.$ One can check that $$A\upharpoonright_{S_{12}}=\{(1,0),(0,1),(1,1),(0,0)\},$$ $$A\upharpoonright_{S_{13}}=\{(1,0),(0,0),(0,1)\},$$ $$A\upharpoonright_{S_{23}}=\{(0,0),(1,0),(0,1)\}.$$
Can we say $\mathcal{A}$ is $(3,2)$-universal set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**
After discussion with @PlayGame, it seems that confusion arises as in the proof, $A$ is defined to be a set, which would imply that the elements are distinct (and thus we lose the independence of strings). To make the proof sensical, we need to define $A$ as a vector of strings. Note that the proof remains correct, because a universal $(n,k)$-vector of size $r$ implies a universal $(n,k)$-set even smaller.

1. This is correct
   **Edit :**
   In fact no, in your probability space, nothing tells you that $a_i\neq a_j~ \forall a_i, a_j \in A, i\neq j$, so $|\Omega| \neq \binom{2^n}{r}$. You have $rn$ binary values to choose, so you have $2^{rn}$ possible choices, so $|\Omega| = 2^{rn}$.
2. Your guess was correct, you are probably confused by the fact that the product is on $A$, since $A$ is a random variable, but in fact, it does not really rely on $A$. If we write $A = \{a_1, a_2,\dots, a_r\}$, we could rewrite the product as $\prod \limits_{i\in
    1,\dots,r}\text{Pr}[v\neq a_i\upharpoonright_S]$, and it no longer depends on $A$.
3. No, because $A\upharpoonright_{S_{13}}$ does not contain every possible string of length $2$. Add $(1, 1, 1)$ and you get a universal set.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and desire to help me! So now I am comfortable with question 1 and 3 since my reasoning was correct. But I am still confused with question 2: what is the $[v\notin A|_S]$? What is the formal definition of that event?

Comment: So is $\{v\notin A|_S\}$ the same as $\{A\in \Omega: v\notin A|_S\}$, right?

Comment: Yes, this is a very common abuse of notation to simplify how we write events.

Comment: Could you clarify your second paragraph please? $A$ is actually some element of $\Omega$, i.e. $A\in \Omega$. Why is this a random variable? As far as I know a random variable is a function $f:\Omega\to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: we know that $\{A\in \Omega: v\notin A|_S\}=\{A\in \Omega: v\neq a|_S\ \text{for all}\ a\in A\}$ and the book says that the last set is equal to $\bigcap\limits_{a\in A}\{A\in \Omega: v\neq a|_S\}$. But formally the last intersection is wrong because the intersection is defined in a circular way.

Comment: @PlayGame Yes, this is not really a random variable, I misused the term a bit. I explained in my answer that the intersection does not really depend on $A$, but only on $r$, so there is no circularity.

Comment: Yes I think I agree with you now but I need to think on this problem trying to understand why those events are independent. I'll spend some time trying to understand that. May I ask you question if I'll fail to do that?

Comment: But I accept your answer as the best one since it helped me to understand some moments!

Comment: May I ask you a question which is bothering me? The books says $\text{Pr}[v\notin A|_S]=\prod \limits_{i=1}^r\text{Pr}[v\neq a_i|_S]$. I guess that this is true due to the independence of events but let's put it aside this step. The book says $\text{Pr}[v\neq a_i|_S]=1-2^{-k}$. I have some issues trying to prove that. But this is what I have so far. WLOG take $i=1$, then we know that $\text{Pr}[v\neq a_1|_S]=1-\text{Pr}[v= a_1|_S].$ But $$\text{Pr}[v= a_1|_S]=\frac{\#\{A\in \Omega: v=a_1|_S\}}{|\Omega|},$$ where $A=\{a_1,\dots,a_r\}$.

Comment: I am trying to compute the cardinality of the set in the numerator. Since $v= a_1|_S$ it means that $k$ coordinates of $a_1\in \{0,1\}^n$ are fixed and each remaining $n-k$ we can fill with $0$ or $1$, i.e. in total $2^{n-k}$ possibilities. But $a_2,\dots,a_r$ can be chosen from the rest $2^n-1$ in $\binom{2^n-1}{r-1}$ ways. Hence the numerator is $2^{n-k}\binom{2^n-1}{r-1}$ and since $|\Omega|=\binom{2^n}{r}$ it implies that $\text{Pr}[v=a_1|_S]=\frac{r}{2^k}$. However, the book says that the answer should be $2^{-k}$. What is my mistake?

Comment: Hello! Can we discuss my question please?

Comment: @PlayGame See my edit. There are $rn-k$ remaining coordinates, so you end up with a probability of $2^{-k}$. You can also see it this way: the probability of one coordinate to be equal to the corresponding in $v$ is $\frac{1}{2}$. As these probabilities are independent and you must have $k$ coordinates matching the ones of $v$, you end up with a probability of $(\frac{1}{2})^k$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135478/discussion-between-playgame-and-caduk).

Comment: Hello! Excuse me please but can we discuss one question? Please let me know

Comment: Hello! Can you let me know when you join a chat please?