# Enumerative combinatorics on $\{0,1\}^n$

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose that $X=\{A\subseteq \{0,1\}^n: |A|=r\}$, where $\{0,1\}^n$ be a family of all binary strings of length $n$.

If $A\in X$, then $A=\{a_1,\dots,a_r\}$. If $S=(i_1,\dots,i_k)$ with $1\leq i_1<\dots<i_k\leq n$, then for any $\bar{\alpha}=(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)\in \{0,1\}^n$ define $\bar{\alpha}|_S=(\alpha_{i_1},\dotsm \alpha_{i_k})$.

I was wondering how to compute the cardinality of the following set $\{A\in X: a_1|_S=\vec{v}\}$ for some fixed $\vec{v}\in \{0,1\}^k$?

My answer is $2^{n-k}\binom{2^n-1}{r-1}$ but I am not sure is this a correct answer or not.

Comment: How do you choose which string is $a_1$ in $A$? The enumeration of the elements in $A$ seems to matter to your computation.

Comment: @Phicar, what do you mean? Can you clarify your question please?

Answer (score 1):

Exactly $k$ components of $a_1$ are determined by $\vec{v}$, so you have $2^{n-k}$ choices for the other $n-k$ components of $a_1$ and then $\binom{2^r-1}{r-1}$ choices for the other $r-1$ vectors in $A \setminus\{a_1\}$.  But this double counts because some other $a_j$ could have played the role of $a_1$.  For example, consider $n=2$, $r=2$, $k=1$, $S=(1)$, and $\vec{v}=(0)$.  There are five such $A$, namely
$$\{(0,0),(0,1)\},\{(0,0),(1,0)\},\{(0,0),(1,1)\},\{(0,1),(1,0)\},\{(0,1),(1,1)\},$$ but your formula yields $2^{2-1}\binom{2^2-1}{2-1}=6$.

I recommend instead considering the complement, where no $a_j\in A$ satisfies $a_j|_S = \vec{v}$.

Comment: Can you explain why this double counts? If you provide some specific example that would be perfect!

Comment: I am slightly confused how one can compute its complement?

Comment: I added a small specific example of double counting.

Comment: Hmm I see it now and I also suppose it should be specifies what do we mean by $a_1$ in $A$, right?

Comment: Yes, $a_1$ is not well defined.  What is the source of this problem?

Comment: Please take a look: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4424100/existence-of-universal-n-k-sets. This is an excerpt from Jukna's book "Extremal combinatorics". I won't be surprised if this is false because the book a lot of typos and some minor mistakes. If you can add something helpful that would be great! Thank you!

Comment: But I agree with you that the object $\{A\in X: \vec{v}\neq a|_S\ \text{for all} \ a\in A\}$ is well defined but I don't know how to compute. Seems a bit messy